# Telerik UI For UWP TimePicker Step property

Tags: xaml, uwp, telerik

I am trying to set the minute increment from 1 to 5 on the RadTimePicker. The telerik document here:

```
https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/raddatepicker-and-radtimepicker/properties-and-configuration/raddatetimepickers-properties-pickerproperties
```

Says that

```
Step (DateTimeOffset): Gets or sets the step that will be applied to the picker date/time lists. Each list will take the correspomding component fron the DateTimeOffset structure.
```

There is no sample code and I do not know what this means or how to do it but I have tried this:

```
   InitializeComponent();
   var t = new DateTimeOffset();
   t.AddMinutes(5);
   timePickerz.Step = t;
```

in the code behind but no good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested the `RadTimePicker` control on my side, there's no problem. For example, If I set `Step` to 6 minutes, the minute selector will step by 6 minutes.

```cs
RadTimePicker myTimePicker = new RadTimePicker();
myTimePicker.DisplayMode = DateTimePickerDisplayMode.Standard;
myTimePicker.Step = new DateTimeOffset().AddMinutes(6);
```

[image]